# Utf-8 en raw_input()

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

No me funciona el utf-8 cuando coloco un raw_input, por ejemplo en

```
raw_input('Ingrese un número')
```

me lo muestra mal, y también si coloco

```
raw_input(u'Ingrese un número')
```

me muestra error, como se debe colocar? aquí dejo codigo de referencia

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def binary_search(numbers, number_to_find, low, high):

    if low > high:
        return False

    mid = (low + high) / 2

    if numbers[mid] == number_to_find:
        return True
    elif numbers[mid] > number_to_find:
        return binary_search(numbers, number_to_find, low, mid - 1)
    else:
        return binary_search(numbers, number_to_find, mid + 1, high)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 25, 27, 28, 34, 36, 49, 51]
    number_to_find = int(raw_input('Ingresa un número: '))

    result = binary_search(numbers, number_to_find, 0, len(numbers) - 1)

    if result is True:
        print(u'Sí se encontró el número en la lista.')
    else:
        print(u'No se encontró el número en la lista.')

    raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ¿Cómo funciona esto de los encodings en python2?

Típicamente hay que comenzar el fuente con una línea como: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

En python2 esa línea simplemente le dice al intérprete python que codificación usó tu editor de texto a la hora de guardar el archivo. Eso lo necesita saber para decodificar correctamente las secuencias de bytes que se encontrará entre comillas en el fuente.

Cuando Python encuentre en el código fuente algo "Entre comillas", lo que en realidad está *viendo* el intérprete es una secuencia de bytes. En general guardará esa secuencia de bytes sin tratar de entender qué caracteres representa (porque de hecho podría no representar carácter alguno, la secuencia de bytes podría ser puramente binaria, como en `"\x05\x12\x07"` por ejemplo).

Si intentas imprimir una secuencia de bytes así, el intérprete se limitará a enviarlos sin más a la terminal, y es la terminal la que tratará de decodificarlos (usando el *encoding* de la terminal), para mostrar caracteres.

Si la terminal no usa el mismo *encoding* que la secuencia de bytes (por ejemplo, si la terminal usa CP-850, mientras que el fichero fue guardado como UTF-8), los caracteres no-ascii no se mostrarán correctamente (los acentos, eñes, etc.) Los caracteres ASCII sí se mostrarán bien porque todos los encodings coinciden en cómo codificar esa parte del alfabeto.

Esto puedes notarlo al ejecutar un código como el siguiente:

```
# coding: utf-8
print "Eñe"
```

Si el fichero efectivamente fue guardado como UTF-8, entonces lo que va dentro de las comillas será la secuencia de bytes: `45`, `C3`, `B1`, `65` (donde `45` es el código UTF-8 de la `E`, `C3` y `B1` en secuencia codifican la `ñ` y finalmente `65` es el código de la `e`).

Si ejecutas ese programa en una terminal que use UTF8, la terminal simplemente recibirá esa secuencia `(45, C3, B1, 65)` y la decodificará como UTF-8, mostrando `Eñe`.

Ahora bien, si lo ejecutas en una terminal que use CP-850 (por ejemplo, una terminal Windows), la terminal mostraría `E├▒e`, pues en ese *encoding* los bytes `45` y `65` siguen representando `E` y `e` (por ser parte del ASCII), pero los bytes `C3` y `B1` representan dos caracteres separados (`├`y `▒`, respectivamente, como puedes ver en [la tabla de códigos CP-850](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_de_c%C3%B3digos_850)).

#### Cadenas unicode

Para evitar este comportamiento errático, en el que lo que muestra depende del *encoding* usado por la terminal, es mejor usar "cadenas unicode", que se diferencian de las normales en que comienzan por `u` (delante de las comillas). El programa anterior quedaría ahora así:

```
# coding: utf-8
print u"Eñe"
```

La diferencia con lo anterior es que ahora Python no trata lo que hay entre comillas como una secuencia de bytes sin significado alguno, sino que sabe que se trata de una cadena de caracteres, por lo que convierte del *encoding* usado por el editor (le tenemos que decir cuál es a través del comentario de la primera línea) a una codificación interna de Python que no depende de la terminal ni del editor ni del operativo. En esta codificación, cada letra de tu cadena se convierte en una letra para python (y no como antes, en que aparecían casos como la `ñ` que, aún siendo una letra aparentemente, eran dos bytes en la representación interna).

Una consecuencia inmediata de esto es que si hacemos `len()` para averiguar la longitud de la cadena, en el primer caso nos hubiera dado 4 (el número de bytes), pero ahora nos dará 3 (el número de caracteres). Esto hace que todas las funciones de manipulación de cadenas se comporten "mejor" (por ejemplo, pasar a mayúsculas, minúsculas, etc. funcionarán correctamente).

Otra ventaja es que a la hora de hacer el print, python intentará averiguar el *encoding* de la terminal y convertirá su representación interna a la secuencia de bytes apropiada para esa terminal, de modo que el usuario vea `Eñe`, lo mismo que escribió el programador.

El inconveniente es que si python no es capaz a determina el *encoding* de la terminal, asumirá ASCII por defecto, y entonces fallará en cuanto se encuentre una letra que no pueda ser representada como ASCII.

Una vez sabemos todo esto:

#### ¿Por qué no funciona `raw_input("Número: ")`?

En realidad funciona a medias, pues al ser una cadena "normal", python no entra a decodificarla. Simplemente la trata como una secuencia de bytes y eso será lo que envíe a la terminal. Siempre que la terminal use la misma codificación que el programa, se verá correctamente. Si no usa la misma codificación se verán mal todas las letras no-ascii (que aparentemente es lo que te sucede a tí)

#### ¿Por qué no funciona `raw_input(u"Número: ")`?

De acuerdo con lo antes explicado, esto *sí* debería funcionar. Pero no lo hace debido a un bug. La función `raw_input()` no usa el encoding de `sys.stdout` (la salida estándar), como hace la función `print`. En lugar de ello asume codificación ASCII y falla cuando encuentra un caracter no ascii.

### ¿Solución?

Ya que el bug impide hacerlo "bien", las soluciones son un poco insatisfactorias:

1. Usa un editor que utilice el mismo encoding que la terminal en que lo vas a ejecutar (y declara esa codificación en el primer comentario del programa)
2. Cambia la codificación de la terminal para que use UTF-8.
3. Recodifica la cadena antes de imprimirla, como en la respuesta de FJSevilla.

O lo mejor de todo: cámbiate a Python3. En python3 todo el soporte unicode es mucho mejor, el bug antes mencionado está corregido, y el encoding por defecto para el fuente es utf8, con lo que no tienes ni que declararlo en la primera línea. El inconveniente es que tendrás que cambiar más cosas en tu programa para que sea compatible con python3 (las más inmediatas: `print()` requiere paréntesis alrededor del argumento; `raw_input()` se llama ahora `input()` y el antiguo `input()` ha desaparecido; todas las cadenas son ahora por defecto unicode en lugar de "binarias", y cuando hagas entrada/salida a disco o por sockets debes manejar explícitamente su conversión a bytes).

De todas formas, python3 es el futuro. Python2 dejará de recibir soporte definitivamente en 2020. ¡Vete preparándote!

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que la terminal de turno (posiblemente CMD-Windows) no usa UTF-8 como página de códigos. Una posible solución es codificar la cadena de acuerdo a la codificación usada por la terminal:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys

n = raw_input("Ingrese un número".decode("UTF-8")
                                 .encode(sys.stdin.encoding))
```

Claro está que la página de códigos de la consola y la fuente de la misma deben soportar el carácter `ó`, por ejemplo *CP 850 (Latin-1)* junto a *Lucida Console*.